# hibernate, join 3 tables

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have 3 beans: Product, Color, Price

Price- Product relation - @ManyToOne

Product- Color relation - @ManyToMany

Each color has 3 product and each product has 3 price

I'll explain my problem: in the Product table i have a field "type" and in the price table i have field "price_min"

Do I need to get all Prices for specified Color ? How do I do this with HQL?

```
Query query =hibernatesession.createQuery("select distinct prlpx from  Color c, Product pr " +
                         "join pr.listPrice prlpx" +
                         "join c.listProduct clpr  where clpr.nom='"+color+"'  " +
                       " AND prlpx.price_min='"+price_min+"' pr.type='x' ");
            listPrice =(List<Price>)query.list();
```

but does not work !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Miss a space in your sql between **prlpx** and **join**.

try this

```
Query query =hibernatesession.createSQLQuery("select distinct prlpx from  Color c, Product pr " +
                         "join pr.listPrice prlpx " +
                         "join c.listProduct clpr  where clpr.nom='"+color+"'  " +
                       " AND prlpx.price_min='"+price_min+"' pr.type='x' ");
```

Note that i used **createSQLQuery**

Comment: sorry, your query did not seem HQL, then was correct createQuery.

Comment: But I'm perplexed about c.listProduct clpr, it means that in Color bean there is the producs list?

Comment: Try this query from the db direclty and see if it fetches results , many a times we are stuck with wrongly written queries

Comment: Is in the Product the list of color?